# Sorting a list of strings in C# to the same order as SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, sorting, binary-search

Does anyone know how I can sort a list of strings in C# to exactly the same order that would be returned by a SQLite query - including for all special characters. I need to perform a binary search on the returned data, however my IComparer is using C#'s String's CompareOrdinal, and therefore doesn't work, as the sort order between the two is different.

I have defined the SQlite table's column as "collate nocase".

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase the question, how can you sort a list of strings ignoring case?

The [StringComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx) class provides comparers that support a specific culture and can optionally ignore case. To sort using your thread's current culture you can use the CurrentCultureIgnoreCase comparer:

```
var myList=new List<string>{"aa2","Aa1"};
myList.Sort(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

The InvariantCultureIgnoreCase or OrdinalIgnoreCase comparers use invariant and ordinal comparisons respectively.

SQLite by default uses BINARY collation which is equivalent to Ordinal (paragraph 6.1 from [DataTypes in SQLite v3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

`Every column of every table has an associated collating function. If no collating function is explicitly defined, then the collating function defaults to BINARY`

Unless, you have changed the collation of the tables, you can use OrdinalIgnoreCase to sort in the same order ignoring case.

You can also create a comparer for a specific culture with the [StringComparer.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.create.aspx) method.

Comment: No. SQLite doesn't know the current culture. It also, i think, obeys some standard for UTF string sorting. "NOCASE – Compares ASCII characters in case-insensitive manner; others are treated as bytes". Not sure this is the same as C#'s CompareOrdinalIgnoreCase..

Comment: Not really. SQLite by default uses binary collation, which is equivalent to Ordinal. It simply compares the byte values